# Getting to a one-column layout when grid items span multiple columns

Tags: html, css, css-grid

When using:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(*size*, 1fr));
```

inside of a grid, everything seems to work perfectly. It creates as many tiles as can fit in the space.

When I add a `grid-column: span 2` to a grid item everything works well until there is only enough space for one item.

Because of the `span 2` the grid never breaks down to just one column, and creates an incredibly small column with the following item and never wraps.

If I take out the `span 2`, it wraps perfectly.

I'd rather not use a media query if possible to address this behavior.

Does anybody have any insight as to why this happens?

Here is a Codepen of the behavior: https://codepen.io/anoblet/pen/BYOeQM

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(450px, 1fr));
}

.span-2 {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.grid-auto {
  background: red;
}

.grid-900 {
  max-width: 850px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid grid-auto">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div class="span-2">3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
<div class="grid grid-900">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div class="span-2">3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Both grids will display the behavior if you resize the window, though the second one will display it right away.

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 3):

> Does anybody have any insight as to why this happens?

Because when you set `grid-column: span 2` on an item it forces the item to span two columns, regardless of screen size. In your code, there is no reason for this item to span one column.

You need to tell the item to switch from two columns to one when the screen resizes. Media queries exist for this purpose.

[**revised codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WMaeNm)

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(450px, 1fr));
  background: red;
}

.span-2 {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

@media ( max-width: 500px ) {
  .grid   { grid-template-columns: 1fr; }
  .span-2 { grid-column: span 1;        }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div class="span-2">3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```